# How to obtain a diff, when creating a file from a command?

Tags: unix, ansible

I'm running a command to (re)create a remote file. I'd like to see a difference between the old and the new versions of the file -- and for the task to set `changed: false`, if there are no differences.

Is there a way to do this without doing it all by hand -- with multiple tasks (creating a backup, running the command, diff-ing the two, etc.)?

Comment: You will need to write a bash script to do that. I don't think there is a command for that, but you could use git.

Comment: Bash, @Jofbr?! If I have to use external code, I'd rather use Python -- at least, I know it is available, or Ansible wouldn't be running... But I'd like to stay within Ansible...

Comment: Yes, Python could work as well.

Comment: Ansible modules such as `file`, `template` already have this logic, and report changed only when file content changes. Also there is a `--diff` option while running `ansible-playbook` which can show the changes.

Comment: Yes, `file` and `template` do -- but `command` does not, apparently. Because there is no way for Ansible to know, what the command does. But I'm willing to tell it: "check this file" or something...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently, this is not currently possible. The best I could come up with was:

1. Run the command with output sent simply to `stdout`, rather than directly to a file. This is possible with many commands (such as with `-o /dev/stdout`), allows to declare it with `changed_when: False` and `check_mode: ansible_check_mode`. Save the results:

```yaml
- name: Run the command to obtain content
  command: foo -
  register: foo
  changed_when: False
  check_mode: ansible_check_mode
  ...
```

2. Use the `copy` module to (re)write the file with the captured output:

```yaml
- name: Write the content into file
  copy:
    dest: /where/ever/it/was
    content: '{{ foo.stdout }}'
  ...
```

This is Ok for when your files aren't too large -- requiring "only" one additional task... One *per file*.

For everything else, I created [this enhancement-request](https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/193).